# Must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008, powershell-1.0

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | Foreach-Object {
$groups = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
$_ | Select-Object @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}},@{n='Groups';e={$groups -join ';'}}
}
```

Hi there...when I run the above mentioned script in server 2008, I getting error mentioned below.

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At C:\Temp\Usrgrp.ps1:4 char:73
+ $_ | Select-Object @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}},@{n='Groups';e={$groups -j <<<< oin ';'}}
```

Can you pls assist me in finding out whats the issue ?

Comment: The formatting in the error message looks a bit strange... did you copy this from somewhere? Looks like it has a strange character in it...

Comment: Yes, I got this for an example to try...

Comment: Also just found that the error is only appearing in powershell v1.0, but in other versions its fine...pls let me know if you can assist me in that...

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit like, what that other guy postet. If Powershel 1 does not support `-join` (I dont really know, but i looks like), you could go with that:

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$adsi.Children | Where-Object {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | Foreach-Object {
    $groups = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
    $_ | Select-Object @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}},@{n='Groups';e={[string]::(';',$groups)}}
}
```